# MD5 hashing in a string in C

Tags: c, hash, md5

I am currently trying to hash two strings together in C using the following MD5 lib:
https://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md5

However, when I run my code (it compiles without warnings), there is a memory error (segfault or something similar).

Where's the error? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Code:

```
#include "md5.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* hashfunc (char* word1, char* word2){
    //concat both words
    strncat(word1,word2,100);
    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    MD5_Update(&md5,word1,strlen(word1));
    unsigned char* digest;
    MD5_Final(digest,&md5);

    return digest;
}

int main(){
    char* a = "dick";
    char* b = "duenn";

    char* ret = hashfunc(a,b);
    printf("MD5 hash: %s\n",ret);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't use `strncat` with the `char*` input like that. What that's doing is appending `word2` to `word1` where `word1`'s memory space is not big enough to hold both.

Comment: And then you are passing an uninitialized pointer to `MD5_Final`. That's another bug. The pointer is where `MD5_Final` writes the result, it has to point at a valid buffer, not just be a random pointer.

Comment: @StoryTeller So all I'll have to do is give that digest pointer some space using malloc?

Comment: Seeing as you return `digest`, yes. But mind the use of `strncat` too. Best use a buffer for that as well.

Comment: Or maybe you don't need to `strcat` at all. It would appear you may call `MD5_Update` on multiple items. Each *added* to the digest.

Comment: Yes I do. @Jeremy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably one of the biggest inconveniences of C is string handling. It's all very low level. `char*` is not simply a string that can be modified and written to however; it's just a pointer to memory.

There are several ways to correct the code, but here is my recommended fix:

```
// hashes two words and writes the digest to output.
void hashfunc(char* word1, char* word2, char* output) {
    //concat both words
    char concat[100];
    strcpy(concat, word1);
    strcat(concat, word2);

    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    MD5_Update(&md5,concat,strlen(concat));
    MD5_Final(output,&md5);
}
```

Changes were:

- Using a temporary work buffer to join the words together to be hashed.
- Not returning a value, instead opting to let the user pass a buffer in to handle the return value.

Benefits of the second change is that the consumer can use memory on the stack rather than always being forced to deal with memory allocations inside of the function. (The other method would be to malloc memory and return that, which is slower and must be freed manually).

Also I'm not exactly sure how the MD5 library you're using works, but you can probably avoid the manual concatenation altogether:

```
void hashfunc(char* word1, char* word2, char* output) {
    MD5_CTX md5;
    MD5_Init(&md5);
    MD5_Update(&md5,word1,strlen(word1));
    MD5_Update(&md5,word2,strlen(word2));
    MD5_Final(output,&md5);
}
```

And in case you need a usage example:

```
char ret[100];
hashfunc(a, b, ret);
```

Comment: That seems to work. However, when I print the digest I get a weird output.
Something along the lines: MD5 hash: �W��I��G� K�

What do I do about that?

Comment: Sounds like it doesn't return a hex string but rather raw bytes. You'd need to add an additional step to convert it to a hex string.

Comment: Are there convenient and easy ways to accomplish this?  Thanks for your help by the way. I appreciate that.

Comment: quick and dirty? `printf("MD5 hash: %02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x\n", ret[0], ret[1], ret[2], ret[3], ret[4], ret[5], ret[6], ret[7], ret[8], ret[9], ret[10], ret[11], ret[12], ret[13], ret[14], ret[15] );` :)

Comment: Thanks, but for some reason this always generates the same string no matter the input. I now always get ffffffd41dffffff8cffffffd9ffffff8f00ffffffb204ffffffe9ffffff8009ffffff98ffffffecfffffff8427e as hash, doesn't matter what I set a and b to.

Comment: oops, looks like you need to cast those printf inputs to an `unsigned char` as well `(unsigned char)ret[x]`. As for it printing the same result, I can't say for certain but you might be mishandling data somewhere.